# Panel for Python how to change Gauge colors and layout to be a semicircle

Tags: python, panel

I am using Panel framework from https://panel.holoviz.org in order to generate graphs in Python. I have generated a Gauge chart using the code form https://panel.holoviz.org/reference/panes/ECharts.html.

My code:

```
import panel as pn
pn.extension('echarts')

def main:
    gauge = {
        'tooltip': {
            'formatter': '{a} <br/>{b} : {c}%'
        },
        'series': [
            {
            'name': 'Incidents',
            'type': 'gauge',
            'detail': {'formatter': '{value}%'},
            'data': [{'value': 50, 'name': f'Stable'}]
            }
        ]
    }
    gauge_pane = pn.pane.ECharts(gauge, width=400, height=400)
    gauge_pane.save(filename="incidents.png")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

**This results in the following gauge graph**

[image]

**However, I want it to be a semicircle that is colorful, like this:**

[image]

How can I edit the graph in such a way that it is more like that I want?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should look at the plotly gauges instead of the panel e-charts:

Plotly gauges: https://plotly.com/python/gauge-charts/

You may use it like:

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import panel as pn
pn.extension('plotly')

fig = go.Figure(go.Indicator(
    domain = {'x': [0, 1], 'y': [0, 1]},
    value = 450,
    mode = "gauge+number+delta",
    title = {'text': "Speed"},
    delta = {'reference': 380},
    gauge = {'axis': {'range': [None, 500]},
             'steps' : [
                 {'range': [0, 250], 'color': "lightgray"},
                 {'range': [250, 400], 'color': "gray"}],
             'threshold' : {'line': {'color': "red", 'width': 4}, 'thickness': 0.75, 'value': 490}}))
your_gauge= pn.pane.Plotly(fig)
your_gauge.servable()
```

Output to the above code:
[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LU5VE.png)